# How to supply Admin credentials in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, passwords, credentials, administrator, silent-installer

I have have created a logon script which will remove users from the local administrators group on each computer. The entire process must run completely silently. The Powershell script must run as Administrator and I have the following code which self-elevates my script:

```
# Self-elevate the script (Run as Administrator)
if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
 if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
  $CommandLine = "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments 
  Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine -WindowStyle Hidden
 }
}
```

The only issue is that for end-users, when they logon, the self-elevation requires an Admin username and password. I need to supply Admin credentials automatically to keep this entire process running completely silently. How can I provide admin credentials?? See image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpmbD.png

Thank you!

Comment: Are the machines all in a domain?

Comment: there is no secure way to do what you are trying to do using a logon script. you cannot store a password on the netlogon share without making it accessible to all domain users. a gpo is the right method for doing this, you can configure the local admins  groups precisely how you need them without leaving (what is effectively) a domain admin password laying out there.

Comment: Run it as a startup script instead of a logon script.

Comment: The Group Policy "Local Users and Groups" preference is the correct way to handle this. Do not use a script.

Comment: The Machine are all on the same domain. 

The thing is we only want to remove certain types of users from the local admin group on each computer. I appreciate the suggestions but I am keeping to my script. My script is working just as I want it to. I just need to supply admin credentials to the field shown in the image. 
@brendan62269

Comment: I have written lots of scripts that require admin creds at go time, if you are dead set on doing it this way then I would look to the googles for creating and consuming pscredential objects within a script and executing commands with elevated rights. you will not be able to encrypt the password running this process as a logon script. you also, probably, aren't going to get someone here to explain how to do that as it is a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy really is the way to go but if you are absolutely deadest on your script you could create a scheduled task that executes your script as SYSTEM.  Make sure that script is not in user-writable space else an attacker will modify it to their liking and get their malicious code executed as SYSTEM.

As @brendan62269 pointed out, if you do put a password out there on a netlogon share it'll take an attacker a trivial amount of time to take that, realize what it is, go to your domain controller, drop the NTDS.dit, and have your entire environment.

Comment: Can you explain how the Group Policy way can be implemented?

Comment: Search for "group policy preferences local users and groups". This is not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Better link (more pictures)
[link](https://www.petri.com/manage-local-active-directory-groups-using-group-policy-preferences)

[link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b3afdea1-34ae-41de-8c9e-ea46d9302edf/how-to-remove-domain-user-group-from-the-local-administrator-group?forum=winserverGP)